# Generating a table with calendar days as column headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, calendar, tabular

I want to create a table having calendar days as headers.  The user inputs a date, for example, December 16. I want this and the next 21 days to display as table headers.

[image: Column Header]

Then rows:

Apple 
Orange 
Mango 
Peach

How can I generate a table in C# wherein I can access each cell getting the date and the row name: (12-16, Apple), (12-17, Apple)?

Comment: What you have tried till? Code please.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [data table](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) with your own columns.
MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the same

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable(); 
//use for loop to created column
for(int i=.....)
{
    //dt.Columns.Add("Name");
}



//DataRow _ravi = dt.NewRow();
//_ravi["Name"] = "test";

//dt.Rows.Add(_ravi);
```